# Reverse HTML tags, understand assignment

Tags: javascript, html

In the following **HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">home</a>
  <a href="about.html">about</a>
  <a href="more.html">more</a>
  <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>
```

one should reverse the `<a>`.

**JavaScript**

Create a reverse array:

```
var n = document.querySelector("nav");
var max = n.children.length;
var arrReverse = [];

for (i = (max - 1); i > -1; i -= 1) {
  arrReverse.push(n.children[i]);
}
```

I thought that this would work:

```
for(j = 0; j < max; j += 1) {
  n.children[j].innerHTML = arrReverse[j].innerHTML;
  n.children[j].href = arrReverse[j].href;
}
```

but it didn't. The output is `contact more more contact`.

Can someone explain, **why** this does not work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3d461d0/)

Comment: It must be storing a reference, but the solution is eluding me, If you store the [text of the children it works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/s3d461d0/1/)

Comment: Side note: you might want to use `var i` and `var j` in your `for` loops in case `i` and `j` exist in a higher scope, otherwise you're overwriting their values.  (Or even better, `let i` if you're working in an ES2015 environment).

Comment: @Liam: I know how to debug! I wouldn't ask this question if I had figured it out. Sometimes one need a little hint to open up the eyes. Your solution is not correct. It does not assign the `hrefs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you change `n.childerns arrReverse` change too

```
var n = document.querySelector("nav");
var max = n.children.length;
var arrReverse = [];

for(i = (max - 1); i > -1; i -= 1) {
  arrReverse.push([n.children[i].innerHTML,n.children[i].href]);
}

for(j = 0; j < max; j += 1) {
  // console.log(arrReverse[j].innerHTML);
  n.children[j].innerHTML = arrReverse[j][0];
  n.children[j].href = arrReverse[j][1];
}
```

Comment: Basically break the object reference again but without cloning everything

Comment: Thank you very much! I have mixed up arrays and objects and didn't recognize it. Nice and clear solution!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are storing references here (because children[i] is object):

```
arrReverse.push(n.children[i]);
```

So your `arrReverse` elements are references to `n`.`children[i]` and not new objects. That's why here:

```
n.children[j].innerHTML = arrReverse[j].innerHTML;
n.children[j].href = arrReverse[j].href;
```

you are getting values that you've changed in a previous loop iteration.

The right code will be:

```
var n = document.querySelector("nav");
var max = n.children.length;
var arrReverse = [];

for(i = (max - 1); i > -1; i -= 1) {
  arrReverse.push(clone(n.children[i]));  //here we store new objects, not references
}

for(j = 0; j < max; j += 1) {
  // console.log(arrReverse[j].innerHTML);
  n.children[j].innerHTML = arrReverse[j].innerHTML;
  n.children[j].href = arrReverse[j].href;
}

function clone(obj)
{ 
   var clone = {};
   clone.prototype = obj.prototype;
   for (property in obj) clone[property] = obj[property];
   return clone;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90txu04L/)

Comment: Ah, yes, the clone breaks the object reference

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make a call to the `DOM` elements in loop, they are changing on each iteration here:

```
for (j = 0; j < max; j += 1) {
    n.children[j].innerHTML = arrReverse[j].innerHTML;
    n.children[j].href = arrReverse[j].href;
}
```

It is better to save the data from them, reverse it, and show it to the user.

```
var n = document.querySelector("nav");
var a = n.querySelectorAll("a"),
    max = a.length;
var arrReverse = [],
    menu = [],
    i, j, k = 0;

// save data
for (k = 0; k < max; k++) {
    menu[k] = {
        text: a[k].innerHTML,
        link: a[k].href
    }
}

// reverse data
for (i = (max - 1); i > -1; i -= 1) {
    arrReverse.push(menu[i]);
}

// print reversed data
for (j = 0; j < max; j += 1) {
    a[j].innerHTML = arrReverse[j].text;
    a[j].href = arrReverse[j].link;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osu4jok8/1/)

`menu = []` stores your data, then you reverse it (in a new array). In the last loop, you just get the data from it and set in the right places.

Hope you are looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the `arrReverse` array, you are storing the elements contained in the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) by reference, so, any change in the original `HTMLCollection` will change the elements in that array. On the other hand, you need to be aware that you are working with the [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property, and it returns a live `HTMLCollection`. This means that any change that you make in the DOM directly will update automatically the `HTMLCollection`.

So, it is easy to understand what is happening:

This is a representation of the `HTMLCollection` returned from `n.children`:

```
0 => <a href="home.html">home</a>
1 => <a href="about.html">about</a>
2 => <a href="more.html">more</a>
3 => <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
```

And this is a representation of the `arrReverse` array:

```
0 => <a href="contact.html">contact</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 3)
1 => <a href="more.html">more</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 2)
2 => <a href="about.html">about</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 1)
3 => <a href="home.html">home</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 0)
```

When you run:

```
n.children[0].innerHTML = arrReverse[0].innerHTML;
n.children[0].href = arrReverse[0].href;

n.children[1].innerHTML = arrReverse[1].innerHTML;
n.children[1].href = arrReverse[1].href;
```

This will be the status of both objects:

**HTMLCollection:**

```
0 => <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
1 => <a href="more.html">more</a>
2 => <a href="more.html">more</a>
3 => <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
```

**`arrReverse` array:**

```
0 => <a href="contact.html">contact</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 3)
1 => <a href="more.html">more</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 2)
2 => <a href="more.html">more</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 1)
3 => <a href="contact.html">contact</a> (reference of the HTMLCollection index 0)
```

So, without continuing the loop, at this moment, both objects have lost the reference to `about` and `home`. The result will be `contact more more contact`.

To avoid this issue in an easy way, we can follow two approaches:

1. Use a non-live collection, and this is possible if
   [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) is used because it returns a static
   (non-live) [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So, in this case, if you change the DOM
   directly, the `NodeList` will not be updated, and this means that it
   is not needed a secondary array to store the data, we can use the
   same data stored in the original collection as far as we don't
   modify directly the elements inside it.
2. To modify the DOM directly (without modifying the elements inside the `NodeList`), [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) could be used, because using
   it directly in the elements will change the `DOM` without changing
   the original elements (read the next quote located in the documentation of this attribute).

> *Also, while the element will be replaced in the document, the variable whose outerHTML property was set will still hold a reference to the original element.*

Here you have the solution following these approaches:

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");

anchors.forEach((a, i) => a.outerHTML = anchors[anchors.length - i - 1].outerHTML);
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">home</a>
  <a href="about.html">about</a>
  <a href="more.html">more</a>
  <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>
```